# Не работает селектор по input + label

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

хочу сделать radio buttons, но не работает селектор на label, имеется следующий код:

```css
.option-variant input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.option-variant input[type="radio"]+label {
  float: left;
  min-width: 40px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="option-variant">
  <label for="option_size1">X</label>
  <input name="option_size1" type="radio" value="1" id="option_size1">
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: мне кажется если Вы текстом напишите чего хотите добиться, то будет лучше

Comment: "хочу сделать radio buttons, но не работает селектор на label". Стили к label не применяются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя в стилях

```
.option-variant input[type="radio"]+label
```

четкая команда выбрать следующий `label` после `input`

а по факту у тебя `label` перед `input`. Поменяй местами

Answer (score 0):

```css
.label-size {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.label-size input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.label-size-text {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}

.label-size input[type="radio"]:checked+span {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-size">
  <input name="option_size1" type="radio" value="1"><span class="label-size-text">X</span>
</label>
<label class="label-size">
  <input name="option_size1" type="radio" value="1"><span class="label-size-text">XX</span>
</label>
<label class="label-size">
  <input name="option_size1" type="radio" value="1"><span class="label-size-text">XXX</span>
</label>
```